# Filter values by Date and ComboBox Vb.Net Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to filter values Between dates and a value from a combobox, I tried:

```
adapter.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM loins LIKE date(dateprocessed) between '" & DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "' and '" & DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "' WHERE projectcode= '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' ORDER BY code ASC", conn.getConnection)
```

And gives the error:

```
Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE date(dateprocessed) between '2021-09-20' and '2021-09-25' WHERE projectcode' at line 1
```

Comment: Try with where instead of like

Comment: The `WHERE` clause needs to contain ALL the filter conditions, not just the one relating to the text column. `LIKE` is used only for comparing text to a value containing wildcards.

Comment: Also, don't build SQL code using string concatenation like that. ALWAYS use parameters to insert values into SQL.

Comment: You really just need to say out loud what you want to do and it will tell you how to write the code. You want records where the date is between those two values and the text column is equal to a particular value. Just write SQL that does that.

Comment: This question is about SQL, not about VB.NET, so I have edited the tags accordingly. The fact that you're using VB.NET to build the SQL code is irrelevant because the SQL would be wrong for the same reason no matter what application language you were using.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments under the question mentioned, all you need to do is to replace the 'like' with the 'where' clause.
Just want to add some optimization to the query :

- Add an index to the 'dateprocessed' column (great if you have already done so). This will keep your queries snappy even when your data grows to millions.
- Do not cast 'DateTime' field to 'date' (like 'date(dateprocessed)') for comparison. There are many unwanted side effects of doing this.

1. First and foremost is that, when you cast your DateTime field to date, your queries won't use index and will start taking extremely long times, as data grows, to finish the query. In my case, querying data for the last 2 days (~ 30,000 rows) out of 70 million rows, for some complicated queries, took 46 mins with date(column) casting, and 6 seconds without that.
2. As the above point implies, the casting may not even be serving any purpose, and may again lead to some errors.

   - The DateTime '2021-09-25 10:21:30' falls between '2021-09-25' and '2021-09-26' even without casting it to date, so will all the other DateTimes between these dates.
   - The DateTime '2021-09-26 11:16:24' will be included in your results even if you are querying for results between '2021-09-25' and '2021-09-26'. This may be something that you want or something unwanted, based on your requirement. If you want to include it, just make your query from '2021-09-25' to '2021-09-27'.